# create json variable from local file + parse

Tags: jquery, json

I currently read a local json file and parse it in javascript as follows:

```
 $.getJSON("steps4.json", function(data){
      $.each(data.data.steps, function(i, step){
        ...
      });
});
```

I'd like to create a variable from the JSON file and use that to manipulate the data (so I don't overwrite what exists in "steps4.json").

I'm hoping it can look something like this:

```
var json_copy = $.getJSON('steps4.json');
$.getJSON(json_copy, function(data){
     // do stuff with the data here
});
```

But of course what I have above doesn't work.  How would you suggest I use the local variable copy to parse the data?

**Solution**

I ended up calling the following function:

```
$(function(){
      $.getJSON("steps4.json", function(data){
        json_copy = data;
        loadMap(json_copy);
      });
    });

 function loadMap(data_json){
      $.each(data_json.data.steps, function(i, step){
       ....
     });
  });
```

Comment: You can't write local files at all.  You don't actually have a problem.

Comment: do you mean that I'm not able to edit the contents of steps4.json using javascript?

Comment: You can manipulate the parsed `data` in memory without altering `steps4.json`. But, you'll have to persist it somewhere else to avoid losing changes when the page is unloaded and memory is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone an object before performing potentially destructive operations on it.

Just stringify it and parse it again

```
var original_json = $.getJSON('steps4.json');
var json_copy=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original_json));
```

The contents of the json file, as it's stored in the hdd, will not change through front-end manipulation of its parsed data.

Edit: just to elaborate on my answer. Let's say that after the parsing of the json file you had

```
var original_json={firstkey: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}};
> original_json
> Object {firstkey: Object}
```

A destructive operation such as

```
original_json.firstkey='This is a String';
   > original_json
   > Object {firstkey: 'This is a String'}
```

Would overwrite the original value of original_json.firstkey.

If you reference it, **it's still overwritten**

```
var original_json={firstkey: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}};
var json_copy=original_json;
json_copy.firstkey='This is a String';
    > original_json
    > Object {firstkey: 'This is a String'}
```

If you clone it instead:

```
var original_json={firstkey: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}};
var json_copy=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original_json));
json_copy.firstkey='This is a String';
    > original_json
    > Object {firstkey: Object}
```

thus saving the need to perform aditional requests if you need the original value of original_json.

Comment: That is completely unnecessary, and won't work either.